# Efficient way to learn LyX

Tags: lyx

what is the best way to learn LyX? My purpose is to write mathematical documents. The tutorials attached to the software are too long, and I am searching for something more convenient.

Comment: Read the introduction (menu help, introduction). It provides a way through the whole documentation, which is very well written. You need to know the basics of LaTeX and LyX. By the way, LyX is a great way to start with LaTeX & Friends. In the beginning the complexity is low, but nonetheless you can write well layouted documents.

Comment: I have some basics, but I want to write more formal articles, since now my results are quite sloppy.

Comment: You always can ask for advice. Please provide a »MWE«, a minimum working example, see here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/4736 In LyX, I guess, you have to export your file to LaTeX to get the MWE. Or you decide to ask for help in the LyX community: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample (no idea about them).

Comment: Just found https://learnlatex.org

Comment: There are different opinions whether to learn LyX first and transition into a deeper understanding of LaTeX, or to start with LaTeX before you learn LyX. No matter which you start with, you will need to eventually learn LaTeX in order to get the most out of LyX for any non-trivial document. My personal opinion is that's it's best to learn LaTeX first. That will help you understand what LyX is doing in the background and will allow you to delegate a lot of things to LyX but also understand how to step in where you want customization.

Comment: One way to learn without read is keep  the code preview pane always open and experiment, comparing what you do in LyX, what you obtain in the LaTeX code and what produce this code in the PDF. At the end you will learn some things, but one of them will be that read a LaTeX tutorial is a faster way.

Comment: @KeksDose I propose for you to write an answer. It would be nice to get this out of the unanswered queue.